# Pip raises ld: library not found for -lssl when I tried to install psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, macos-ventura

I have problem regarding install requirements in my project and install `psycopg2`.
It raises an error.

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
```

My system: `Mac Air M1 2021 OS Ventura 13.4.1 Python 3.9`

**I tried to fix with:**

- `brew install openssl` and `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/`
- `xcode-select --install`

But this solutions isn't helps for me. Maybe anyone know how to fix that ?

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but have you tried installing `psycopg2-binary` instead?

Comment: The same error when I tried `psycopg2-binary`

Comment: If you aren't married to Homebrew, this is a class of problem [Nix](https://nixos.org/) packages don't have, because their dependencies are all in hash-addressed locations fully controlled/managed by Nix itself (and the packages are generally developed and tested on Linux, where Nix has a strictly-enforced sandbox that prohibits any package from accessing files that _don't_ come from a declared dependency at build time; that sandbox doesn't work as well on MacOS, but one still gets the benefit of packages that have been tested to build with it in place).

Answer (score 0):

First, you may need openssl version 1.1.x specifically:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Then, try using environment variable `LDFLAGS`, with a `-L` prefix, rather than `LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib
```

or perhaps:

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib:$LDFLAGS
```

You may also want to ensure that you have the latest version of pip installed:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Finally, try building and installing psycopg2 again:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

This worked for me just now on my Mid-2014 MacBook Pro (Intel-based), running macOS Big Sur 11.7.9. Hopefully it works for you as well, in spite of the differences in macOS version and architecture.